# Why does Java allows strange syntax for array variables which mixes two syntax styles (like String[] p[])?

Tags: java, arrays

I have just suddenly found an interesting fact about array variables in Java.
It is allowed to mix both syntax types.
For example, the parameter `p` in the following code is a 3-dimentional array (tested on JDK 11.0.2):

```
class Main {
    static void m(String[] p[][]) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        m(new String[][][]{});
    }
}
```

Why is that actually allowed? Can it be called a bug in the Java compiler?